# Swift - How to move view by keyboard frame changes?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I want to update view's frame by changes of keyboard frame.

I implemented using `UIKeyboardWillShow` and `UIKeyboardWillHide`. But it's working only when keyboard is completely shown or hidden.

But I need to catch the frame changes in real time on `UIScrollView` or `UITableView`. When we set `Keyboard` property of `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` to `Dismiss interactively`, keyboard is scrolling when scroll the table view or scroll view.

I want to capture the keyboard frame changes while scrolling.

**Slack did it.**

How can I do it? I appreciate any help.

Thank you!